# Find lines in one "key - value-list" file that contain data fields not mapped to that key in a second "key-value" file

Tags: text-processing, csv

I have 2 files. One file contains a minimum of two fields (a username, an age, and a variable number of "fruits" each in their own field) per line, the other file always contains two fields per line (the username and one "fruit"). I would call `file1` the "database" file and `file2` the "mapping" file.

For each username I want to check if any of the lines in `file1` corresponding to that user contains a "fruit" that is *not* mapped to that user as per `file2`.

Example:

- `file1` (the number of fruits in each row is variable in this file):

  ```
  james,25,strawberry,rassberry,blueberry
  james,25,strawberry,rassberry,mango
  james,26,blueberry
  james,27,pineapple
  erik,30,strawberry,rassberry,mango
  ```
- `file2`:

  ```
  james,strawberry
  james,rassberry
  james,blueberry
  erik,blueberry
  erik,rassberry
  ```
- Desired output:

  ```
  james,25,strawberry,rassberry,mango
  james,27,pineapple
  erik,30,strawberry,rassberry,mango
  ```

  These lines are selected because `file2` contains no associations of `mango` or `pineapple` with user `james` and no association of `strawberry` and `mango` with user `erik`.

I was only able to get partial solution with my code. I have tried below, but this is not checking for other columns in the same row.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}
{if (a[$1] && (a[$1]!=$3)){print $0, a[$1]}}' file2 file1
```

Comment: Why is `james,27,pineapple` outputted? Why isn't `james,25,strawberry,rassberry,blueberry` outputted?

Comment: Because pineapple does not exist for james in file2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk -F, '
    !nxtfile{ join[$1]= (join[$1]==""?"": join[$1] FS) $2; next }
            { split(join[$1], tmp, ","); for(x in tmp) fruits[tmp[x]];
              for(i=3; i<=NF; i++) if(!($i in fruits)) { print; break }
            }
' file2 nxtfile=1 file1
```

in the first block we are processing the input *file2* and joining all the fruits in different lines together for the same *name* and store them as pair of key/value into the associated array called *join*.

in the second block we are processing the input *file1* and fetch the value of the matched first field from the array and split that on comma delimiter into a temporary array *tmp*, then we rebuild another array *fruits* with the values of the *tmp* array used as keys for *fruits* array (in other word, we are swapping the *tmp* array's values to become the keys to the *fruits* array).

then the last step is to looping over the >=3<sup>rd</sup> field to the end and checking one by one if that fields is exist in the *fruits* array, on  a first non-matching field we print the entire line and break the loop as there is no need to continue reading rest of the fields.

Comment: @afshin - looks like it is getting the desired output. Could you explain in detail ?

Comment: @congen I added some explanation, hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Certainly more lines than the accepted awk solution, but maybe clearer if you don't know awk (like me).

This uses Python's sets, which allow us to cleanly ask, "does this list of fruits have an element (fruit) that isn't in the lookup/reference list?":

```py
import csv
import sys
from collections import defaultdict

# Will look something like { james: [strawberry, ...], erik: [blue, ...] }
lookup = defaultdict(set)

with open('file2', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)

    for row in reader:
        name, fruit = row
        lookup[name].add(fruit)


writer = csv.writer(sys.stdout)

with open('file1', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)

    for row in reader:
        name = row[0]
        these_fruits = set([x for x in row[2:] if x])

        # see my note below on how set.difference(set) works
        if not these_fruits.difference(lookup[name]):
            # no difference
            continue

        writer.writerow(row)
```

Here's how `set.difference(set)` works:

```py
>>> {1,2}.difference({1,2,3})
set()
>>> {1,2,3}.difference({1,2,3})
set()
>>> {1,2,4}.difference({1,2,3})
{4}
```

It isn't until the left-hand side has an element that the right-hand doesn't that there appears to be a difference.